# how to delete the files not on $home in destination with rsync

Tags: rsync

I am using `rsync` from my `$HOME` as:

```
rsync -avr * /run/media/MyBackup --delete
```

This command,as  expectd, will not delete any file on $HOME, but only work on the folders.

Is there any way to delete files $HOME is destination that is not present in src?

Answer (score 0):

You are expanding your list of what you want rsync to work in with the shell (via *).   The shell won't expand files that are missing, so rsync doesn't touch them.

You probably want to let rsync expand the directory instead.   This will differ in that it would pick up dotfiles as well.   If you don't want that, you could create an exclude rule for it.

`rsync -avr "$HOME/" /run/mediaMyBackup --delete` would be something to try.